# Files and directories are missing in .NET MVC template

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET platform and I'm studying the MVC pattern using the .NET Core CLI. When I create a project using the MVC template:

```
dotnet new mvc -o MVCProject
```

everything goes fine. However, I realized that some directories and files like the `RouteConfig.cs`, `App_Start/`, `App_Data` and `Web.config` are missing.

[This is my project tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn9CX.png)

[.NET Core info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQshb.png)

I can't use Visual Studio (just VS Code), because my OS environment is Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). Why my MVC project does not have the files and directories mentioned?

Comment: Asp .Net Core Mvc is not the same as Asp .Net Mvc. Check the Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows\

Comment: Thank you, Liazar! Now, it makes sense...